# Sequelize afterUpdate hook doesnt fire when adding new association, only fires if I change a property

Tags: sequelize.js, associations, hook

Im trying to run some auditlogging on sequelize afterUpdate hook, and I need it to allways run. It only runs if I change a value on the updated instance. It doesnt run if I add a assoication without changing something on the parent instance.

Thanks in advance !